# How do i run the second if statement once if the condition is met and then never again

Tags: javascript

```
function CheckUpgrades(){
    if(cookies >= 1000){
        document.getElementById("upgrades").style.removeProperty("display");
    }
    if (clickMultiplier == 2){
        document.getElementById("upgrades").style.display = "none";
        //cookies = cookies - 500; MAKES IT GO IN REVERSE
    }
}
```

I have this in an interval because i need to keep checking the conditions.

Comment: Add an additional boolean flag with an `&&` and flip it after the second statement is run once.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to this that fixed it.

var upgradeBought = false;
var upgradePossible = false;

function CheckUpgrades(){
    if (upgradePossible) {
        if (!upgradeBought) document.getElementById("upgrades").style.removeProperty("display");
        else document.getElementById("upgrades").style.display = "none";
    }

```
if(cookies >= 1000) upgradePossible = true;
```

}
setInterval(CheckUpgrades,1000/60);